# can we create directory in view? django

Tags: python, django, static, directory

I want to create / remove directories in static folder using django's view.  Is it possible?

Something like, when I run django's view I want to create some extra folders in static folder...then do some processing inside the folder, and remove them later

Comment: do you have some code to share so that I can help you ?

Comment: @sasuke really yet, I have been searching for create / remove directory using django view but not much luck :(

Comment: @Tsuna Don't mean to be rude but if my answer has helped you, can you please mark it accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create/remove directories from a Django view using **os** and/or **shutil**.

Your views.py will go something like this -

```
import os, shutil, errno
from django.conf import settings

def my_view(request):
    #Getting static folder path from project settings
    static_dir = settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0]

    #Creating a folder in static directory
    new_dir_path = os.path.join(static_dir, "new_dir")
    try:
        os.makedir(new_dir_path)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            #directory already exists
            pass
        else:
            print(e)

    #Removing a directory
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(new_dir_path)
    except OSError, e:
        print(e)

    #do the things you want
```

**Note:** `os.rmdir(path)` can also delete a directory but only if it is empty.